# MongoDB: is it better to have a large collection, or many smaller ones with joins?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a `Meteor.users` collection. Since each user "type" has different profiles, the user collection can get rather big. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
{
  profiles: {
    player: "someplayerid",
    admin: null,
    battlenet: null
  },
  roles: {
    "somegroupid": [
      'player'
    ],
    "someothergroupid": [
      'admin',
      'player'
    ]
  }
}
```

Then in my queries, I am doing a pseudo-join in order to query groups, roles, and profile. Eg:

```
Meteor.publish('players', function () {
  // all _ids of those with role "player" in "somegroupid"
  var profileIds = Roles.getUsersInRole('player', 'somegroupid').map(function (doc) {
    return doc.profiles.player;
  });

  return Players.find({
    _id: {
      $in: profileIds
    }
  })
});
```

Is it better to simply add the object directly into the `Meteor.users` collection, in this case? In the mongo docs, it says:

> Do joins while write, not on read

Which method of doing it is considered better for mongodb?

Answer (score 2):

> is it better to have a large collection, or many smaller ones with joins?

In your case I would use a large collection. Joins are expensive because it means you need multiple round trips to the database, as well as the need to join these in your code.

Also consider the line:

```
  var profileIds = Roles.getUsersInRole('player', 'somegroupid').map(function (doc) {
    return doc.profiles.player;
  });
```

Imagine you have 1,000,000 players. Do you really want to fetch all information about all these players, strip out their ID, create an array in memory of size 1000000 and then "upload" this array back to Mongo for another query? This is very expensive in terms of memory and CPU.

With the large collection, you would only need to create one query, and then iterate over the cursor response of that query (very memory efficient).

Comment: There is an other issue with joins you didn't mention: as MongoDB do not have transaction, you have to be prepared for a foreign reference to disappear between your two queries.